# Time gets included when importing Date Cells from Excel to ASP SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, excel, gridview

I'm importing an Excel file to SQL through ASP.NET and a certain column includes dates (2/31/2000) with a cell format of (*d/mm/yyyy).

When I import the Excel file in ASP.NET, the data suddenly becomes like this in the gridview

```
2/31/200 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format Date in Gridview...

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

Comment: can this be done on rowdatabound? because i have so many columns and it's hard to create bound fields for each

Comment: how? i tried something like this String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", e.row.cells[6].text) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really ask a question.  Is this after a round trip from uploading through asp.net storing in SQL server and then retrieving from DB and displaying in gridview?  .net uses the datetime type  If you want to display only the date portion you can use

```
DateTime exceldate = new DateTime();
exceldate.ToShortDateString();
```